# reversing each word in sentence using python

Tags: python

I'm new in python. I'm trying to reverse each word in the sentence. I wrote following code for that and it is working perfeclty.

My code:
[From answer]

```
import re
str = "I am Mike!"

def reverse_word(matchobj):
    return matchobj.group(1)[::-1]

res = re.sub(r"([A-Za-z]+)", reverse_word, str)
print(res)
```

But I want to add one condition in that..only words should reverse not any symbol.[ except alphanumerical words and words contains hyphen]

Updated##

Sample:
input: "I am Mike! and123 my-age  is 12"

current output: "I ma ekiM! dna123 ym-ega si 12"

required output: "I ma ekiM! 321dna ege-ym si 21"

Comment: Should `"don't have a cow!"` reverse to `"t'nod evah a woc!"`, or `"nod't evah a woc!"`? If it's the former, how do you distinguish between symbols that don't count as part of a word, and symbols that do?

Comment: since both letters and symbols are string - you'd probably want to make a list of symbols you want to skip like "symbols = ["!", "?", ...] and just skip them while you're looping. but as Kevin mentioned - you'd definitely have to decide on how to distinguish symbols from word parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Regex: [([A-Za-z]+)](https://regex101.com/r/sx4v8u/1)

You can use the character class `[A-Za-z]` for checking any word with one or more length, capture it then reverse the group 1 using a function using the [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.sub) function.

```
import re
str = "I am Mike!"

def reverse_word(matchobj):
    return matchobj.group(1)[::-1]

res = re.sub(r"([A-Za-z]+)", reverse_word, str)
print(res)
```

Outputting:

```
'I ma ekiM!'
```

---

**Update:**

You can [tweak the code](https://regex101.com/r/G76inZ/1) a little to acheive your results:

```
import re
str = "I am Mike! and123 my-age is 12"

def reverse_word(matchobj):
     hyphen_word_pattern = r"([A-Za-z]+)\-([A-Za-z]+)"
     match = re.search(hyphen_word_pattern, matchobj.group(1))
     if match:
         return re.sub(hyphen_word_pattern, f"{match.group(2)[::-1]}-{match.group(1)[::-1]}", match.group(0))
     else:
         return matchobj.group(1)[::-1]

res = re.sub(r"([A-Za-z]+\-?[A-Za-z]+)", reverse_word, str)
print(res)
```

Outputting:

```
I ma ekiM! dna123 ega-ym si 12
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. it's working well..i forgot to add something that continuous seq of alphanumerical char and char with a hyphen should reverse normally...what changes should i do?

Comment: @user2809967 please update that into the question details.

Comment: @user2809967 can you add sample input output for your updated question

Comment: sample input output added

Answer (score 2):

Don't use re at all

```py
def reverse_words_in_string(string):
    spl = string.split()
    for i, word in enumerate(spl):
        spl[i] = word[::-1]
    return ' '.join(spl)
```

gives
'I ma !ekiM 321dna ega-ym si 21'

Answer (score 0):

One approach which might work would be to make an additional iteration over the list of words and use `re.sub` to move an optional *leading* punctuation character back to the end of the now reversed word:

```
s = "I am Mike!"
split_s = s.split()
r_word = [word[::-1] for word in split_s]
r_word = [re.sub(r'^([^\s\w])(.*)$', '\\2\\1', i) for i in r_word]
new_s = " ".join(r_word)
print(new_s)

I ma ekiM!
```